# How do I set the NLS_DATE_FORMAT for the Database Reader node in Knime?

Tags: sql, oracle, knime

I am using the following SQL in the Knime Database Reader node with Oracle Driver:

```
SELECT
TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:mi:ss') “NOW”
FROM DUAL
```

The result contains the correct Date but the time is always 00:00:00.

If I run the same query Oracle LiveSQL or DBfiddle I have the accurate time as well.

See: [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1d661405bf1fc7e361c38d4b4d379284)

The reason I think it works in DBfiddle and LiveSQL is because I am setting **NLS_DATE_FORMAT**.

How do I set the NLS_DATE_FORMAT for the Database Reader node in Knime?

Comment: Why are you passing sysdate, which is already a date, into `to_date()`? Does your question, and your comment on the now-deleted answer, imply that you are *intentionally* relying on implicit conversion and NLS settings? If so, why? Both should be avoided...

Comment: SYSDATE is just an example. What gets passed in is something as follows: 
" TO_DATE((DATE '1970-01-01' + ( 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000) * registration.timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:mi:ss') AS registrationdate"

Comment: That's still passing something *that is already a date* into a function that converts a string to a date. That doesn't really make sense. It sort of works (except when it doesn't), but only by implicitly converting the date value into a string, only to immediately convert it back to a date again. What are you trying to achieve by doing that?

Comment: In other words: why aren't you just doing `DATE '1970-01-01' + ( 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000) * registration.timestamp AS registrationdate` or even `DATE '1970-01-01' + (registration.timestamp/86400000) AS registrationdate` ?

Comment: here is what I am trying to do:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cb823294ee7c3b87f121b36dfeea5a01

This works in

Comment: But [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5d2a5b5ded8806fcd1cdfa7f9fb97e84) will work anywhere. (Your client still needs to format the date/time for display at some point, but that doesn't seem to be an issue).